# Generate video thumbnail using ffmpeg; Grab from RTMP server

Tags: ffmpeg, rtmp, flash-media-server

I have research how to generate a video thumbnail user FFMPEG like so:

`ffmpeg -i myfile.flv -vcodec mjpeg -vframes 1 -an -f rawvideo -s 640x480 foo.jpg`

But how can I generate a thumbnail when the file is on another server? Specifically a RTMP server? for example: `rtmp://foo.rtmphost.com/videos`

Comment: please ask such questions on superuser.com, it's not about programming problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use [rtmpdump](http://rtmpdump.mplayerhq.hu/) to save stream to flv file and then to use FFMPEG to extract thumbnail from it.

something like:

```
rtmpdump -v -r rtmp://[stream_address] -o 1.flv
```